# irritating div with content

Tags: html, css

Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/8wSzk/2/

```
<div class="row1">
<div>
    <div class="circle-menu">
    </div>
    <p> some option </p>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="circle-menu">
    </div>
    <p> some option <br /> and <br /> another option </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
<div>
    <div class="circle-menu">
    </div>
    <p> circle3 </p>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="circle-menu">
    </div>
    <p> circle4 </p>
</div>
</div>
```

I want my both circle to be in a straight line with its content just below the circle. can somebody help me fixing my css. I am quite new to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want. If you want to have two elements side to side, you must use the `float` attribute. In this case, it would be `float:left;`.

**EDIT**
[NEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8wSzk/6/)

Comment: i want to keep my content below the circle

Comment: yes i want my circle to be aligned in a row and content below should appear just below the circle.

Comment: I think that the OP wants the text "aligned" with the circles. I would say that p { text-align: center; }

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
<div class="row1">
    <div>
        <div class="circle-menu">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="circle-menu">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row1">
    <div>
        <p> some option </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p> some option <br /> and  another option </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't want to do like this as i want to keep circle and its content as a single element

Comment: @user2847429 your '<br>' is making the problem then.If you remove that your code itself will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

[New fiddle Code:Works Perfect](http://jsfiddle.net/8wSzk/7/)

Here you go mate, redone it for you. Have a look through it and see what I've done

```
<div class="row1">
<div class="circle-menu">
</div>
<div class="circle-menu">
</div>
</div>
<div class="options-row">
<div class="option">Some option
</div>
<div class="option">Some more options
</div>
</div>
<div class="row2">
<div class="circle-menu">
</div>
<div class="circle-menu">
</div>
</div>
<div class="options-row">
<div class="option">Even more options
</div>
<div class="option">Got the idea?
</div>
</div>

.row1 {
height:90px;
}
.row2 {
height:90px;
}
.circle-menu {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
display: inline-block;
float:left;
background-color: #cacece; 
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%; 
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 5px;
}
.option {
display:inline-block;
width:80px;
margin: 5px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:top;    
}
.options-row {

}
```